# Record audio playing in the App

Tags: ios

My app enables mixing of beats and allows user to play the mixed tune.
I now want to record the tune being played in my App and save it without any of the surrounding/external noises.
Is there a way to achieve this? 
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want noise reduction algorithms? I'm sure there are plenty out there in the wild. Also, why don't you completely bypass the microphone input and directly write to file whatever buffers you play?

Comment: @Mar0ux, i only want to record audio being played from my App. Any links that can help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to take any *user input*? If not (as it looks from your post), what I'm suggesting is this: instead of playing *and then* recording, why not directly write the buffers to file. If you play and then record, you'll inevitably end up with some noise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about iOS, but I know this is an extremely difficult thing to do in OS X. In OS X is requires a kernel extension.

If it is possible, it would be somewhere in the [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation.